# Selected value do not change on setValue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I try to update select value in `mat-select` when I update form by `setValue` I can see that form has been updated and `this.form.value` equals to the user input but selected value is still empty.

```
<mat-select [formControl="form"]>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items">....</mat-option>
 <mat-option> <input (keyup)="updateForm($event.target.value)" /></mat-option>
</mat-select>

form = new FormControl()

updateForm(value) { 
  this.form.setValue(value)
}
```

**UPD 1**.

Well I have found out that if I would mutate items array and add new value from input in array then select can see the new value. But it still bad way that I can see

Answer (score 1):

This part seems wrong `[formControl="form"]`. Please try it like this:

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="form">
  <mat-option *ngFor="....">....</mat-option>
  <mat-option> <input (keyup)="updateForm($event.target.value)" /> </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: yes it was a typo , but anyway not working . logging form I can see that value is updated to my texting message but I cant see that select was selected new value

Comment: I can't reproduce it, can you please provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using 2-way binding to the value property? I think it's simple and doesn't require Angular forms Source: [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

In your HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="object.item">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of listOfItems"
                 [value]="item">{{ item.desig }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you missing value properties of

it should be <mat-option [value]="...">